# ¿Por qué cerramos las discusiones con un "y punto pelota"?

Tags: modismos, expresiones, españa

Se dice con frecuencia *... y punto pelota* para dar por terminada una discusión:

> - Mamá, ¿puedo ir al cine?
> - No.
> - ¡Pero si ya hice los deberes!
> - He dicho que no y punto pelota.

Así [lo indica Fundéu](http://www.fundeu.es/consulta/y-punto-pelota-1755/) y creo que es una expresión bastante corriente, al menos en España.

Sin embargo, no consigo encontrar referencias sobre el origen de esta expresión. Yo la interpreto así:

Un punto indica el final de algo. Luego de alguna forma dicha connotación de final será más fuerte cuanto mayor sea ese punto. Si visualizamos un punto tan grande como una pelota (¿de fútbol?) entonces es que queremos dar una imagen muy contundente de final.

Pero todo es intuición, ¿tiene sentido?

---

<sub>Veo que tenemos las etiqueta [modismos](/questions/tagged/modismos) y [expresion](/questions/tagged/expresion). ¿No sería modismo un subconjunto de expresiones?</sub>

Comment: Quiero aclarar que por Colombia jamás he escuchado tal expresión. Por aquí decimos "...y punto" únicamente. Además de España ¿dónde más la usan?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tras realizar una búsqueda por internet sobre el origen de la expresión "y punto pelota", la explicación más plausible me parece la que expongo a continuación.
Citando una respuesta de [éste](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/punto-pelota-punto-y-fin.964454/) foro, podemos leer:

> Título del artículo: Punto y pelota, Autor: Alex Salmon: "La expresión
>   nos viene al pelo. Explica el final de una frase periodística. Los
>   diarios del siglo XX acaban los textos con un punto y una grafía que
>   simbolizaba una redonda negra como una pelota. Los diarios modernos ya
>   no la utilizan."

A juzgar a partir de la explicación expuesta, se trataría de una grafía particular utilizada en periódicos deportivos del siglo pasado. En otro foro he encontrado también la posible grafía, la cual se sugiere como sigue:

> (.•)

En efecto, éste simbolo se utilizaría para dar por concluido el articulo en turno. 
Dada la poca fiabilidad de las fuentes, sólo quiero aclarar que mis conclusiones son meramente especulativas.

Comment: Yo diría que sí se sigue usando pero que ha cambiado la forma. No es raro ver artículos que marcan el final tipográficamente, especialmente si constan de más de una página; lo que creo que sucede es que la forma de la «pelota» ha cambiado y lo que más se ve (y hablo desde la estadística más personal y seguramente más sesgada del mundo) es el cuadratín negro, como en este ejemplo: http://www.manuguerrero.es/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/fragmento-art%C3%ADculo-josedo.jpg

Comment: ¡Interesante! En los comentarios de esta entrada de blog se mencionan otros posibles orígenes: http://romera.blogspot.com.es/2007/02/punto-pelota.html La pelota vasca es uno y otro el punto de bordar.

Answer (score 2):

Efectivamente la "pelota" hace referencia a un elemento tipográfico que se añadía tras el último punto final de un artículo y tenía forma de un punto gordo, de ahí lo de pelota. No era exclusivo de los periódicos deportivos, de hecho hasta hace poco la he visto utilizar a veces al final de ciertos artículos en un periódico tan conocido en España como El País pero ignoro si actualmente lo siguen usando en su edición impresa.

Comment: ¡Hola Ramón! Gracias por la respuesta, que incide en lo dicho en [la respuesta de Jose María](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/16368/1674). Por curiosidad, ¿recuerdas más o menos cuándo viste tales artículos? Para intentar encontrarlos en la hemeroteca. Dado que es un periódico relativamente nuevo (de 1977, si la memoria no me falla), querría decir que es un recurso estilístico usado hasta hace poco.

Answer (score 0):

Agrego mi propia especulación a la respuesta aceptada orientándola al porqué precisamente "punto pelota".

Bien podría ser un caso de [aliteración](http://www.retoricas.com/2009/06/5-ejemplos-de-aliteracion.html). Como se explica en esta página:

> La Aliteración es una figura retórica que consiste en la repetición de sonidos presentes en palabras contiguas o próximas.
>
> La Aliteración tiene la virtud de captar la atención y provocar un efecto de musicalidad y sonoridad... Es también una poderosa herramienta para recordar palabras y frases por lo que es muy usada en oratoria y publicidad.

Luego se mencionan varios ejemplos:

> **B**ajo e**l** a**l**a a**l**e*v*e del le*v*e a**b**anico → repetición de los sonidos [l] y [b]
>
> Los **ruido**sos **ron**quido**s** **re**tumbaban sin parar.
>
> **S**ona**ban** **suave**mente **sus** **sabias** palabras.

De esta manera, estando en un contexto deportivo, pelota no es una palabra inusual. Y por empezar con "p" podría agregarle sonoridad a la frase.